# Unable to add service reference

Tags: wcf, http, wcf-endpoint

I am unable to connect to a WCF service hosted on our dev server but I am able to browse to it.
I am just trying to add a service reference via Visual Studio and when I click on Go, it gives me the following error.

**An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://...Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.**

My other colleagues are able to add the service reference and connect to this service with no issues, which makes it harder for me to understand the cause of this issue.

Web.config - system.serviceModel:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/> 

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483646" />
      <security mode="None">
        <!-- **WARNING** Changes to the security binding must also be made in client binding code -->
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service name="X.X.X.RepositoryService" behaviorConfiguration="repositoryServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
    binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding" 
    contract="X.X.X.ICatalogServiceContract" />
    <!-- ** NOTE Metadata not supported SSL at this time **-->

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="repositoryServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />


      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/> 

      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>



    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

Comment: Please provide your App.Config for your WCF app and for your Client here.

Comment: Did you "see the server logs for more details"?